# Watch a PHP variable as XDebug Breakpoint

Tags: debugging, xdebug

Iam using DBGp protocol to communicate with XDebug and so far its great. I can break on specific line numbers with no difficulty. I tried to make a watch and got error `breakpoint type is not supported`, which is clear that XDebug currently does not implement it. What made me ask this is, I have seen many IDEs with this feature (Eclipse included) and wondered how do they implement it. I want to watch expression like

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
```

I want IDE to break there so that I can update a watch window with new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDebug does not support watches. So I had to add that logic to my app to fool around breakpoints to act as watches